# How exactly does tf.data.Dataset.interleave() differ from map() and flat_map()?

Tags: tensorflow, tf.data.dataset

My current understanding is:

**Different map_func**: Both  `interleave` and `flat_map` expect "A function mapping a dataset element to a **dataset**". In contrast, `map` expects    "A function mapping a dataset element to another **dataset element**".

**Arguments**: Both `interleave` and `map` offer the argument num_parallel_calls, whereas `flat_map` does not. Moreover, interleave offers these magical arguments block_length and cycle_length. For cycle_length=1, the documentation states that  the outputs of interleave and flat_map are equal.

Last, I have seen [data loading pipelines without interleave](https://cs230.stanford.edu/blog/datapipeline/#building-an-image-data-pipeline) as well as [ones with interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance). Any advice when to use `interleave` vs. `map` or `flat_map` would be greatly appreciated

---

//EDIT: I do see the value of interleave, if we start out with different datasets, such as in [the code below](https://docs.w3cub.com/tensorflow%7Eguide/performance/datasets_performance)

```
  files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("/path/to/dataset/train-*.tfrecord")
  dataset = files.interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset)
```

However, is there any benefit of using `interleave` over `map` in a scenario such as the one below?

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files("/path/to/dataset/train-*.png")
dataset = files.map(load_img, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Answer (score 18):

**Edit:**

> Can map not also be used to parallelize I/O?

Indeed, you can read images and labels from a directory with `map` function. Assume this case:

```
list_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(my_path)

def process_path(path):
 ### get label here etc. Images need to be decoded
 return tf.io.read_file(path), label

new_ds = list_ds.map(process_path,num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

Note that, now it is multi-threaded as `num_parallel_calls` has been set.

The advantage of `interlave()` function:

- Suppose you have a dataset
- With `cycle_length` you can out that many elements from the dataset, i.e 5, then 5 elements are out from the dataset and a `map_func` can be applied.
- After, fetch dataset objects from newly generated objects, `block_length` pieces of data each time.

In other words, `interleave()` function c**an iterate through your dataset while applying** a `map_func()`. Also, it can work with many datasets or data files at the same time. For example, [from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#interleave):

```
  dataset = dataset.interleave(lambda x:
    tf.data.TextLineDataset(x).map(parse_fn, num_parallel_calls=1),
    cycle_length=4, block_length=16)
```

> However, is there any benefit of using interleave over map in a
> scenario such as the one below?

Both `interleave()` and `map()` seems a bit similar but their use-case is not the same. If you want to read dataset while applying some mapping `interleave()` is your super-hero. Your images may need to be decoded while being read. Reading all first, and decoding may be inefficient when working with large datasets. In the code snippet you gave, AFAIK, the one with `tf.data.TFRecordDataset` should be faster.

**TL;DR** `interleave()` parallelizes the **data loading step** by *interleaving* the I/O operation to read the file.

`map()` will apply the data pre-processing to the contents of the datasets.

So you can do something like:

```
ds = train_file.interleave(lambda x: tf.data.Dataset.list_files(directory_here).map(func,
                            num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
```

`tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE` will decide the level of parallelism for buffer size, CPU power, and also for I/O operations. In other words, `AUTOTUNE` will handle the level dynamically at runtime.

`num_parallel_calls` argument spawns **multiple threads** to utilize multiple cores for parallelizing the tasks. With this you can load multiple datasets in parallel, reducing the time waiting for the files to be opened; as `interleave` can also take an argument `num_parallel_calls`. Image is taken [from docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#parallelizing_data_extraction).

[image]

In the image, there are 4 overlapping datasets, that is determined by the argument `cycle_length`, so in this case `cycle_length = 4`.

---

**FLAT_MAP:** Maps a function across the dataset and flattens the result. If you want to make sure order stays the same you can use this. And it does not take `num_parallel_calls` as an argument. Please refer [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) for more.

**MAP:**
The `map` function will execute the selected function on every element of the Dataset separately. Obviously, data transformations on large datasets can be expensive as you apply more and more operations. The key point is, it can be more time consuming if CPU is not fully utilized. But we can use `parallelism APIs`:

```
num_of_cores = multiprocessing.cpu_count() # num of available cpu cores
mapped_data = data.map(function, num_parallel_calls = num_of_cores)
```

> For cycle_length=1, the documentation states that the outputs of
> interleave and flat_map are equal

`cycle_length` --> The number of input elements that will be processed concurrently. When set it to `1`, it will be processed one-by-one.

**INTERLEAVE:** Transformation operations like map can be parallelized.

With parallelism of the map, at the top the CPU is trying to achieve parallelization in transformation, but the extraction of data from the disk can cause overhead.

Besides, once the raw bytes are read into memory, it may also be necessary to map a function to the data, which of course, requires additional computation. Like decrypting data etc. The impact of the various data extraction overheads needs to be parallelized in order to mitigate this with **interleaving** the contents of each dataset.

So while **reading** the datasets, you want to maximize:
[image]

*Source of image: deeplearning.ai*

Comment: Hi @Frightera, I really do appreciate the time you've taken to answer and upvoted it. However, unfortunately I struggle to extract the key differences between map() and interleave() from it :(. Does the one only parallelize CPU-tasks and the other also I/O tasks? Is it related to processes vs threads? Also, can you cite an article, from which you extracted the image?

Comment: I edited the answer, see if it is clear now. I took the image from a video actually, that is available on coursera.

Comment: Hi, @Frightera. It is really helpful to read you answers. Could you share Coursera course it is?

Comment: Hi @user1269298, thanks. It's been a while but I guess the course was: https://www.coursera.org/learn/data-pipelines-tensorflow?specialization=tensorflow-data-and-deployment

Comment: Man, this is kind of a frustrating read. Maybe I'm missing some assumed, background information. For example: "With cycle_length you can out that many elements from the dataset, i.e 5, then 5 elements are out from the dataset and a map_func can be applied.
After, fetch dataset objects from newly generated objects, block_length pieces of data each time." I'm assuming that "out elements from the dataset" might mean something similar to batching? I can't tell from the context.